# How to use ondblclick to fire "callto:number"

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I display a list of phone numbers using ng-repeat.
Each number is enclosed in div and I would like to fire callto event when user double clicks on it.
I don't have problem with passing paramaters, etc. I've just can't figure out what syntax I should use.

Thanks in advance for all ideas.

Edit:

In simple words, how to get below working.

```
ng-dblclick="callto:1111"
```

Comment: Can you share the current code which you have written?

Comment: Looks like you are looking for [AngularJS ng-dblclick Directive](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-dblclick.asp)

Comment: @SudhirOjha exactly, but how to use it? simple ng-dblclick="callto:1111111" does not work.